# Android : How to update listview item?

Tags: android, listview

I have a `ListView` which contains a **list of products**. Each list item contains a `TextView` which shows the **quantity in the cart**, if the product is in the cart.

The cart is a popup and the product quantity can be changed from the cart.

The issue is when I dismiss the cart pop up, the quantity in the list item view is not updated since the `getView` is not called.

I am aware of `PopupWindow.OnDismissListener` but dont know how to update the view explicitly or call `getView` forcibly.

Is there a way I can achieve this? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So from your question I guess, you're passing a `ArrayList` of `Product` in your adapter. So lets just assume the `Product` class looks like this.

```
class Product {
    public String productName; 
    public int quantity;
}
```

Now when you update the quantity from the cart, you need to update the `ArrayList` which you have passed to the adapter and then call `notifyDataSetChanged()` on the adapter to see the changes in the list.

So I'm writing some pseudo code for changing the quantity from the cart.

```
public void changeQuantity(int index, boolean quantityIncreased) {
    if(quantityIncreased) products.get(index).quantity = products.get(index).quantity + 1;
    else  products.get(index).quantity = products.get(index).quantity - 1;
}
```

Now Override your `PopupWindow.OnDismissListener` like this. Call `notifyDataSetChanged` to see the effect in your list.

```
@Override
public void onDismissListener() {
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: I considered calling `notifyDataSetChanged` but it will refresh the whole layout. Just a look at the pop up, the item that user was viewing will be gone, back to where he started. Thats the problem.

Comment: I didn't quite get you. The item that user was viewing will be gone - what did you mean by this? And yes, don't save the intermediate actions taken on the list?

Comment: I meant the list will be reset and will have to go down again to look further.

Comment: No it should not. And if it does, you can always set the scroll position to the last saved scroll position of you list. In that case, save the current position before calling `notifyDataSetChanged()`.

Comment: That makes sense, `getFirstVisiblePosition()` will do it. I'll try that. Thank you!

Comment: Glad to know that helped.

Answer (score 0):

If you are passing the list of PRODUCT objects via `BaseAdapter` constructor,
You can get the position of the item whose cart is clicked by  `getChildAt(position)`.
If the cart quantity is changed, based upon above position you can trace the item in `ArrayList` as well.
So pass the new value at particular product at arraylist and call `notifyDataSetChanged()`. This will update your listview

If possible,I recommend to update `ListView` to use `RecyclerView`, It is more flexible than `ListView`.

Comment: Cart contains all the items, and cart is popped on another button click, not any product. I am looking at resetting the data and calling `notifyDataSetChanged`, which I want to avoid.

Comment: Okay but how will recycler view help?

Comment: ListView is deprecated and replaced with RecyclerView. The approach for both are somehow similar . The recyclerview adapter have function such as notifyItemChanged(position), which will check the particular item not the entire item

Comment: I'll try that, Thanks.